# Using RNN for text generation it always predicts the same letter

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to create a simple text (name) generator using RNN.  I create the model fine but when I try to predict values I always get the same letter.

My code is as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras.activations import softmax
from tensorflow.keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

# parameters
LSTM_NODES = 100
MAX_NAME_LEN = 30
STOP_MARKER = '.'

# hyper-parameters
EPOCHS = 10

# read _names.train into an array
names = open('names.train', encoding='utf-8').read().strip().split('\n')

# precompute the number of samples
SAMPLES = 0
for name in names:
    for _ in name:
        SAMPLES = SAMPLES + 1

# get a sorted list of all unique characters used
corpus = sorted(list({l for name in names for l in name}))

# the first letter in the corpus must be the stop indicator
corpus.insert(0, STOP_MARKER)

# write out the corpus so that the predict script can use it
open('corpus.txt', 'w').write('\n'.join(corpus))

# calculate the input shape for the network
input_shape = (MAX_NAME_LEN, len(corpus))

# Creating a mapping from unique characters to indices
char2idx = {u:i for i, u in enumerate(corpus)}
idx2char = np.array(corpus)


def get_text(sample):
    t = ''
    for x in sample:
        n = idx2char[np.argmax(x)]
        t = t + n
    return t


# I need a 3-D array, samples x character position x character one-hot encoded
X = np.zeros((SAMPLES, MAX_NAME_LEN, len(corpus)), int)
Y = np.zeros((SAMPLES, len(corpus)), int)

# for each sample name
for name in names:
    # number of samples for this name is equal to the number of letters (we add one letter per loop)
    for i in range(len(name)):
        j = 0
        # create one sample
        while j <= i:
            one_hot_letter = np.zeros(len(corpus), int)
            one_hot_letter[char2idx[name[j]]] = 1
            X[i, j] = one_hot_letter
            j = j + 1
        # get the next character in the sequence
        one_hot_next = np.zeros(len(corpus), int)
        if j < len(name):
            one_hot_next[char2idx[name[j]]] = 1
        # add this character to the Y sample
        Y[i] = one_hot_next
        # print this sample
        print('X={} Y={}'.format(get_text(X[i]), idx2char[np.argmax(Y[i])]))

# build the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(LSTM_NODES, input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(input_shape[1], activation=softmax))
model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

# train the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=EPOCHS)

# save the model
model.save('model.h5')

# try a sample prediction
# first letter is the seed
SEED = 'M'
name = SEED
x = np.zeros((1, input_shape[0], input_shape[1]), int)
one_hot_letter = np.zeros(len(corpus), int)
one_hot_letter[char2idx[SEED]] = 1
x[0, 0] = one_hot_letter
for i in range(1, MAX_NAME_LEN):
    predictions = model.predict(x)
    # get the next letter and add it to the prediction
    next_letter = np.zeros(input_shape[1], int)
    next_letter[np.argmax(predictions[0])] = 1
    x[0, i] = next_letter
    name = name + idx2char[np.argmax(next_letter)]
    print(name)
```

The output at the end is:

```
Mww
Mwww
Mwwww
Mwwwww
Mwwwwww
Mwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?  My samples are fine I think.  I used them in another example written by someone else and they produced different results.  I have 280 samples.  Here is what `names.train` looks like:

```
Adaldrida
Celendine
Gloriana
Pimpernel
Tanta
Alfrida
Cora
Goldilocks
Melba
```

The full output from the training is:

````
[snip]
X=Valde......................... Y=m
X=Valdem........................ Y=a
X=Valdema....................... Y=r
X=Valdemar...................... Y=.
2020-03-09 13:38:26.827190: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-03-09 13:38:26.843439: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fa8f211d590 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-03-09 13:38:26.843450: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 100)               58800     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 46)                4646      
=================================================================
Total params: 63,446
Trainable params: 63,446
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Train on 1795 samples
Epoch 1/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 2s 1ms/sample - loss: 0.0168
Epoch 2/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 462us/sample - loss: 0.0167
Epoch 3/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 445us/sample - loss: 0.0164
Epoch 4/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 450us/sample - loss: 0.0163
Epoch 5/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 449us/sample - loss: 0.0162
Epoch 6/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 453us/sample - loss: 0.0160
Epoch 7/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 593us/sample - loss: 0.0159
Epoch 8/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 599us/sample - loss: 0.0160
Epoch 9/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 442us/sample - loss: 0.0160
Epoch 10/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 440us/sample - loss: 0.0160
Mw
Mww
Mwww
Mwwww
Mwwwww
Mwwwwww
Mwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwww
Mwwwwwwwwwww
[snip]```
````

Comment: What’s the output of your model.fit() does the loss and accuracy change during training?

Comment: Are you initializing weight with np.zeros() if yes this do not work with gradient descent.

Comment: Train on 1795 samples
Epoch 5/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 449us/sample - loss: 0.0162
Epoch 6/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 453us/sample - loss: 0.0160
Epoch 7/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 593us/sample - loss: 0.0159
Epoch 8/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 599us/sample - loss: 0.0160
Epoch 9/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 442us/sample - loss: 0.0160
Epoch 10/10
1795/1795 [==============================] - 1s 440us/sample - loss: 0.0160

Comment: if you can show output here (by editing post) it can help us.

Comment: And no I am not initializing the weights to zero.

Comment: Try using a smaller learning rate and use dropout if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no problem in your code and training method, however I think you get different result from different data set can come from 2 possible cause.

1) you did not train the model good enough and result in under-fitting problem. I think your model is not over-fitting because your data set doesn't seem to have only 'w' that follow 'M'. ( Maybe I'm wrong,you can check your data set and your output distribution)

2) It comes from your `char2idx` and `idx2char` mapping. Because you are trying to create a mapping dictionary from index and character from the corpus itself, it can result in different mapping for each corpus. You can solve this problem by creating a common mapping dictionary for each character and use it for training and predicting in every data set for maintaining mapping consistency (you can save your mapping dictionary as JSON file). For example, letter 'a' will always be [1,0,0,0,...], letter 'A' will always be [0,1,0,0,...] in every training and predicting. Moreover, because you are trying to do character base prediction, you need to have the number of your output layer equal to the number of your character so that you can have a probability distribution over all possible characters.

**Tip**

For debugging purpose, you must print out your probability distribution, in this case is `predictions` variable, just to see the distribution of your model so you will know that your model is underfit or overfit.

Answer (score 3):

This has been asked and answered before [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924452/what-to-do-when-seq2seq-network-repeats-words-over-and-over-in-output).

To summarize, the issue is called *text degeneration* and [the (awesome) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59407187/1939934) to the previously asked question links to an [excellent paper addressing this exact problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09751). To quote the authors:

> Why is text produced by pure sampling so degenerate? In this work we
>   show that the "**unreliable tail**" is to blame. This unreliable tail is composed of tens of thousands of candidate tokens with relatively low probability that are over-represented in the aggregate.

They find that simple sampling can lead to loops or repetitions as generative models will keep sampling tokens that form sequences that are **too** probable, i.e., repetition is less "surprising" than novel tokens. Compare the baseline of greedy sampling to methods that explicitly truncate the unreliable tail:
[image: Figure]

> Figure 9, [Holtzman et al. (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09751)

So first, [as Ronakrit mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60675672/1939934), you should be outputting a vector of logits (probabilities) over a fixed dictionary of tokens.

Then, pick a decoding strategy a little more sophisticated than greedy sampling. TensorFlow ships with [beam search](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_beam_search_decoder) and [top-k](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/top_k?hl=en), but I'd recommend starting with random decoding, for which you can see a worked out implementation in the [TensorFlow Text generation tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation#try_the_model):

```
# Generate probabilities from the model.
for input_example_batch, target_example_batch in dataset.take(1):
  example_batch_predictions = model(input_example_batch)
  print(example_batch_predictions.shape, "# (batch_size, sequence_length, vocab_size)")

# Sample from model outputs.
sampled_indices = tf.random.categorical(example_batch_predictions[0], num_samples=1)
sampled_indices = tf.squeeze(sampled_indices,axis=-1).numpy()

# Look up tokens from the dictionary.
print("Input: \n", repr("".join(idx2char[input_example_batch[0]])))
print()
print("Next Char Predictions: \n", repr("".join(idx2char[sampled_indices ])))
```

Answer (score 0):

So I tried a simple experiment with your code, and reduce the learning rate on adam optimizer to 0.00001, and below is the result:

```
Train on 1453 samples
Epoch 1/30

AEcOOOOONfffffwfwffwfpXWHfHHfA
BEEcOOOfffffwfwfwzffwfzffAdfWH
CEEccOOffffffwfwfwzfffpigMIwHH
FEcOOOOffffffwfwfwfzffwfWgCwHH
MEEcOOcffffffwfwfwfpXW.WggCIwH
PEEcOfffffffwfwfwzffwfzfzfAfAd

1453/1453 - 10s - loss: 0.0162
Epoch 2/30

AEEEcOcOOOOOffffwffwffpbWAHfHH
BEEEEccOOOfffffwffwffpbWAHfHHf
CEEEcEcOOOffffffwffwfpbWAHfHHf
FEEEccOOOOOfffffwffwffpbWAHfHH
MEEEcOOOOOOcOOONfffwfffFFooewG
PEEEcOOOOOOONcffffwffwffWpbAHH

1453/1453 - 4s - loss: 0.0162
Epoch 3/30

AEEEEcOOOOOcOOOOONcuuuullNulXy
BEEEEcOOOOOOOONcOOONEOEFFFFFFC
CEEEEcOOOOOOOONcOOONEOEFFFFFFC
FEEEEcOOOcOOOOOONcOOEOEOEFFFFF
MEEEEcOOOOOOOONcOOONEOEFFFFFFC
PEEEEcOOOOOOOONcOOONEOEFFFFFFC

1453/1453 - 4s - loss: 0.0162
Epoch 4/30

AEEEEOOOOOOOOONcOOONEOEFFFFFFF
BEEEEEcOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEOEFFFFF
CEEEEEcOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEOEFFFFF
FEEEEOOOOOOOcOOOONONcuuuulllXy
MEEEEOOOOOOOOONcOOONEOEFFFFFFF
PEEEEEcOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEOEFFFFF

1453/1453 - 4s - loss: 0.0162
Epoch 5/30

AEEEEOOOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEOEFFFFF
BEEEEEOOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEOEFFFFF
CEEEEEOOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEOEFFFFF
FEEEEOOOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEOEFFFFF
MEEEEOOOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEOEFFFFF
PEEEEEOOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEOEFFFFF

1453/1453 - 4s - loss: 0.0162
Epoch 6/30

AEEEEOOOOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEEFFFFF
BEEEEEOOOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEEFFFFF
CEEEEEOOOOOOOOOOOONcOEOEEFFFFF
FEEEEOOOOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEEFFFFF
MEEEEOOOOOOOOOOOONcOOEOEEFFFFF
PEEEEEOOOOOOOOOOOONcOEOEEFFFFF

...

Epoch 26/30

AOOOOOOOOOOOEOEOOEOEOEOEEEEEEE
BOOOOOOOOOOOOEOEOEOOEEOEEEEEEE
COOOOOOOOOOOOEOEOEOOEOEEEEEEEE
FOOOOOOOOOOOOOEOEOOEOEEOEEEEEE
MOOOOOOOOOOOOEOEOEOEOEOEEEEEEE
POOOOOOOOOOOOEOEOEOOEOEEEEEEEE

1453/1453 - 4s - loss: 0.0159
Epoch 27/30

AOEEEEEEEEEEEEEEOEOEOEOEEEEEEE
BOEEEEEEEEEEEEEEOEOEOOEEEEEEEE
COEEEEEEEEEEEEEEOEOOEOEEEEEEEE
FOOEEEEEEEEEEEEEOOEOEOEOEEEEEE
MOEEEEEEEEEEEEEEOEOEOEOEEEEEEE
POEEEEEEEEEEEEEEOEOOEOEEEEEEEE

1453/1453 - 4s - loss: 0.0155
Epoch 28/30

AEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
BEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
CEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
FEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEOEEEEE
MEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
PEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

1453/1453 - 4s - loss: 0.0165
Epoch 29/30

AEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
BEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
CEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
FEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
MEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
PEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

1453/1453 - 4s - loss: 0.0158
Epoch 30/30

AEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
BEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
CEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
FEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
MEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
PEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

1453/1453 - 4s - loss: 0.0159
```

As you can see, initially, it doesn't always generate the same letter, but on epoch 29 it generates the same letter, it means that your learning rate was too high.

But of course, there's still a problem which is it doesn't seem to learn (underfitting), this time you need to do more experiments, i'd guess that it's more likely because how you model the input and output, in my experience, if I want to make a next prediction, I usually model it this way:

```
X -> Y
Adaldrida -> daldrida.
```

And get the output from each time step, instead of only from the last time step by using `return_sequences=True`, similar to what this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation) describe.
unlike how you model it:

```
X -> Y
A -> d
Ad -> a
Ada -> l
etc.
```

Using that kind of input-output modeling, I think you'll encounter problems such as there would be too many zeros after first character, and the network would have ignored the first character, you might wanna try to use pre-padding, so the trailing zero would be at the start, not at the end, or you can also try to reverse the sequence.

Another reason why your model might not learn, maybe you should try to add more data or tweak the max name length.